# InputNumber submit

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces, primefaces-extensions

I have a problem with InputNumber from primefaces extensions. I have an inputnumber component on my form and when I enter a value in form and right after that I press ENTER button page is submitted but without that value in inputNumber field. It only works when that field loses focus. I checked in [showcase](http://fractalsoft.net/primeext-showcase-mojarra/sections/inputNumber/advanceUsage.jsf) but there were the same problem. In my case, that field is required and when I press enter button, value is gone and validation message that says that value is missing is shown. Any help?

Comment: Your Question is not clear

Comment: It looks like a bug in the component.

Comment: Most likely it is a bug. I fixed it in similar way that is described in answer below, but it definitely should work without it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set your input as **required="true"** then catch the **"enter"** key and change focus to an otherInput like below; Run it on your `.xhtml` page between `<script type="text/javascript"> </script>` tags.

```
$( 'form' ).bind('keypress', function(e){
   if ( e.keyCode == 13 ) {
         document.getElementById('Input10_input').focus();
   }
 });
```

It works also for [showcase](http://fractalsoft.net/primeext-showcase-mojarra/sections/inputNumber/advanceUsage.jsf).

Good Luck!